Is the equality of two arithmetic expressions over R decidable?
On MathOverflow, question Decidability of equality of elementary expressions was asked, and their elementary expression construction only involve constant $i$, operation $\times$, and functions $\exp$ and $\ln$. If we ask a more basic question - giving two arbitrary arithmetic expressions over real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, could we check the equality of the two by an algorithm?
We can realized the equality of two arithmetic expressions over rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is decidable: Given the two expression, we can evaluate both of them into two rationals, and then find a common denominator, to convert the question to the equality of two natural numbers.
But for real numbers, does such an algorithm exists?
Finally, I want point out that this equality problem lays at the center of how we define arithmetic expressions. The only way to define an arithmetic expressions is purely a syntactical way. The semantic validity of the built expressions must avoid the zero-divisor cases which can be reduced to the question here.
Formally, the construction process of an arithmetic expression $a$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is a structure given by the following production rules:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:productionrule}
\begin{aligned}
    a &\longleftarrow  x\\
    a &\longleftarrow ( a + a )\\
    a &\longleftarrow ( a - a )\\
    a &\longleftarrow ( a \times a )\\
    a &\longleftarrow ( a \div a )
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $x \in \mathbb{F}$. This process build a tree. But the process is syntactical, we may not so easy to check the validity of the built expressions.
Then we can recursively define evaluation of $a$ which referred as $\nu(a)$:

Constant leaf: for any $x \in \mathbb{F}$, $\nu(x) = x$.
Compositional node by $+$: For any $(a + b)$, $\nu((a + b)) = \nu(a) + \nu(b)$.
Compositional node by $-$: For any $(a - b)$, $\nu((a - b)) = \nu(a) - \nu(b)$.
Compositional node by $\times$: For any $(a \times b)$, $\nu((a \times b)) = \nu(a) \nu(b)$.
Compositional node by $\div$: For any $(a \div b)$, if $\nu(b) \neq 0$, then $\nu((a \div b)) = \nu(a) / \nu(b)$.

P.S.
Add three related questions here:

Richardson's theorem for constants
Determining the equality of two real numbers
How do you validate that two math expressions are equal?


No , it is undecidable whether some expression (possibly involving limits) is equal to $0$.

Thanks, Peter, could you give some references?

here

But Richardson's theorem are involving more functions like sine? How about remove these functions in the language?

In order to feed an instance of this question into a computer, you need some finite representation. How are you feeding real numbers into the computer?

@TomKern we can symbolically compute an expression with some constant like $\pi$, $e$. And I guess that is why sine function appeared in Richardson's theorem. Thanks.
